# Apache Reverse Proxy Config?

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

can someone tell me what is wrong with my reverse proxy setup? I can successfully auth with ldap but I just get the Apache2 Default Page

I tried putting the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse setting into the Location block but I get the following error on starting Apache

> ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a
> location

I was following the Arkime guide https://arkime.com/faq#how-do-i-proxy-arkime-using-apache

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test-arkime.domain.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/arkime/etc/test-arkime.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/arkime/etc/test-arkime.key"
  ProxyPass        /arkime/ http://localhost:8005/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse /arkime/ http://localhost:8005/
  RequestHeader set ARKIME_USER %{REMOTE_USER}e
 <Directory />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Enter account credentials"
  Require valid-user
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
  AuthLDAPSubGroupClass group
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN On
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.domain.com:389/OU=USERS,DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
  AuthLDAPBindDN ldap@domaion.com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword password123

  require ldap-group "CN=Users,OU=IT Users,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=CORP,DC=domain,DC=com"
 </Directory>
 ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

I just get the Apache2 Default Page

[Apache2 Default Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idzrz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out for the most part, I can now hit Arkime, I now just need to figure out why it's not recognising or maybe not passing the arkime_user through

{"success":false,"text":"User not found"}

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName test-arkime.domain.com
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/arkime/etc/test-arkime.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/arkime/etc/test-arkime.key"
  # redirect from root to subdirectory
  RedirectMatch ^/$ /arkime/
<Location /arkime/>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Enter account credentials"
  Require valid-user
  ProxyPass        "http://localhost:8005/" retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse "http://localhost:8005/"
  RequestHeader set ARKIME_USER %{REMOTE_USER}e
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member
  AuthLDAPSubGroupClass group
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN On
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap.domain.com:389/OU=com,DC=domain,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
  AuthLDAPBindDN ldap@domain.com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword Password123
  require ldap-group "CN=Users,OU=IT Users,OU=Security,OU=Groups,OU=com,DC=domain,DC=com"
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```